# PHP / Laravel - Adding arrays to already set arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on something for me.

Im creating an array with the following code in Laravel.

How can i add the $graphs array to each $website_array in the loop?

```
   $website_array = [];
    foreach ($websites as $website) {
        array_push($website_array, $website);

        $graphs = [
            'thisdata' => 'This data',
            'newdata' => 'New data',
        ];
    }
```

What i want to end up with is something liek the following

```
website
  website data
  website data
  website data
    graphs
      thisdata
      newdata
website
  website data
  website data
  website data
    graphs
      thisdata
      newdata
```

Comment: `array_push($website_array, $graphs);` perhaps?

Comment: @MarkBaker no that creates a whole new array element

Comment: Well perhaps if you explained what you actually want in more detail, an example of what is contained in your $websites, and how $graphs relates to $websites

Comment: Create array of object

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like below which you may also [Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/637707):

```
<?php

    $website_array              = [];
    $websites                   = [
        "http://www.domain-1.com/a",
        "http://www.domain-2.com/b",
        "http://www.domain-3.com/c",
        "http://www.domain-4.com/d",
        "http://www.domain-5.com/e",
        "http://www.domain-6.com/f",
        "http://www.domain-7.com/g",
    ];

    foreach ($websites as $website) {
        $graphs = [
            'thisdata'  => 'This data',
            'newdata'   => 'New data',
        ];
        $data   = [
            'website'   => $website,
            'graphs'    => $graphs,
        ];
        $website_array[] = $data;
    }




    var_dump($website_array);
    // PRODUCES:
    array (size=7)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'website' => string 'http://www.domain-1.com/a' (length=25)
          'graphs' => 
            array (size=2)
              'thisdata' => string 'This data' (length=9)
              'newdata' => string 'New data' (length=8)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'website' => string 'http://www.domain-2.com/b' (length=25)
          'graphs' => 
            array (size=2)
              'thisdata' => string 'This data' (length=9)
              'newdata' => string 'New data' (length=8)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'website' => string 'http://www.domain-3.com/c' (length=25)
          'graphs' => 
            array (size=2)
              'thisdata' => string 'This data' (length=9)
              'newdata' => string 'New data' (length=8)
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          'website' => string 'http://www.domain-4.com/d' (length=25)
          'graphs' => 
            array (size=2)
              'thisdata' => string 'This data' (length=9)
              'newdata' => string 'New data' (length=8)
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          'website' => string 'http://www.domain-5.com/e' (length=25)
          'graphs' => 
            array (size=2)
              'thisdata' => string 'This data' (length=9)
              'newdata' => string 'New data' (length=8)
      5 => 
        array (size=2)
          'website' => string 'http://www.domain-6.com/f' (length=25)
          'graphs' => 
            array (size=2)
              'thisdata' => string 'This data' (length=9)
              'newdata' => string 'New data' (length=8)
      6 => 
        array (size=2)
          'website' => string 'http://www.domain-7.com/g' (length=25)
          'graphs' => 
            array (size=2)
              'thisdata' => string 'This data' (length=9)
              'newdata' => string 'New data' (length=8)
```

Comment: No, this creates the graphs array outside of each website, i need them nested i.e website 1 has graphs 1, website 2 has graphs 2

Comment: @BigJobbies   Post updated... check it out here: https://eval.in/637707

Answer (score 0):

First create class 'ClassWebsite'

```
class ClassWebsite
{
  public $website;
  public $graphs;
}
```

And use it

```
$website_array = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($websites as $website) {
  $obj_class = new ClassWebsite();
  $obj_class->website = $website;
  $graphs = [
      'thisdata' => 'This data',
      'newdata' => 'New data',
  ];
  $obj_class->graphs = $graphs;
  $website_array[$i] = $obj_class;
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Why should he 1st create a Class for that purpose?